# Parameter List: Meaning of Parenthesis after Name

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to understand some Fortran code that was passed to me. This is the argument list in a subroutine:

```
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: NKT
REAL, INTENT(IN)    :: NW2(NKT), VAR, SUE
REAL, INTENT(INOUT)   :: MYSPC(NKT,NKT)
```

I understand the declarations of NKT, VAR, and SUE. But what is the meaning of "(NKT)" and "(NKT,NKT)" in NW2(NKT), MYSPC(NKT,NKT)? Does NKT specify the dimensions of the arrays NW2 and MYSPC? Or is it saying the subroutine stores the passed value in the NKTth position of NW2?

I'm really confused by the usage of () after a variable. It's not covered in the "Introduction to FORTRAN 90" book by Nyhoff. Any help would be appreciated.

(Code is a modified segment of Wavewatch, http://polar.ncep.noaa.gov/waves/wavewatch/)

Comment: You are probably not reading the book carefully enough.

Comment: I clicked on this question just to see what a `fortran` question looked like... :D

Comment: The reason you stumbled here is probably that not just the style of array declaration is "old", but also the way of passing arrays to procedures. In your example, `NW2` and `MYSPC` are *automatic* arrays, which get their size automatically from the `NKT` argument. From Fortran 90 or later, you will often see this done using *assumed-shape* arrays like `NW2(:)` and `MYSPC(:,:)` which assume the shape of the actual argument passed, without requiring you to explicitly pass their size as done here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, NW2(NKT), is an array with NKT elements, MYSPC(NKT,NKT) is a NKTxNKT 2D array. If your Fortran book doesn't cover this, really, get a better book. If you have some previous programming experience, I recommend "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf, Reid, and Cohen.

Answer (score 3):

It's the old style of declaring an array.  Your book probably emphasizes the new style of `dimension ()` before the `::`.   Some might consider it an advantage of this style that arrays and scalars can be mixed on the same declaration, as is done in the second line of your example.  I prefer the new style.

Comment: It may look nicer, but it is just too verbose.

Comment: You're right - dimension is covered but the older style does not appear to be (in my book). Thanks for making the connection between the two styles!

Answer (score 1):

To possibly help you reconcile this with your book, consider that

```
REAL, INTENT(IN)    :: NW2(NKT)
REAL, INTENT(INOUT)   :: MYSPC(NKT,NKT)
```

is equivalent to

```
REAL, INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(NKT)  :: NW2
REAL, INTENT(INOUT), DIMENSION(NKT,NKT)  :: MYSPC
```

These are two ways of saying the same thing when declaring arrays.