# Fortran: Variable initialization wwith parenthesis

Tags: variables, initialization, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to understand a Fortran90 code. In the code, I found this expression for initializing a variable:

integer :: time(8)

What is meant by this? What does the parenthesis do?

Comment: Vladimir F, could you please link me to the duplicate? I have not been able to find an answer to my question in other threads?

Comment: This one is a more exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349309/parameter-list-meaning-of-parenthesis-after-name I will not change the duplicate reason by re-opening and re-closing, it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax declares an INTEGER rank one array of size eight.

(In Fortran terminology that source does not initialize anything and it is a declaration, not an expression.)

Comment: Thank you! An a rank one array - that is just a number, right? Ans size eight means 8 bytes?

Thus, the statement declares an 8 byte integer?

Comment: No.  It declares a one dimensional array that has eight elements - there are eight "numbers".  How many bytes each element occupied depends on the Fortran compiler in use.  This is really basic syntax - you should avail yourself of a Fortran textbook or similar.